# How to use the Appery.io REST API with Ruby on Rails to retrieve information from the Appery.io database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, rest, http

How can I access the Appery.io (or any future db) that is exposed to the REST API using RoR?

So I have an app i built using Appery.io and I also created a test app using RoR that I would like to use to pull information from the Appery.io db and display it on my RoR app.

I am somewhat familiar with REST and get the idea of what it is doing but I am not to certain on how to connect or make a connection from my RoR app to my Appery.io app. Appery.io has the following documentation for their db api, [Appery.io DB API](http://devcenter.appery.io/documentation/backendservices/database/) .

I have been looking around and also have seen people mention the following gems for HTTP request:

1. Weary
2. HTTParty
3. RestClient

Would I use one of those? I also read about using Active Resource as a possible solution?

Any help with getting started or a tutorial or article to point me in the right direction would be very helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You won't be establishing an ongoing connection, each request/response will be a single query to your Appery DB. You authenticate those calls using a custom header with API key as defined in the documentation. There's an [example using cURL](http://devcenter.appery.io/documentation/backendservices/database/#REST_curl_command) that might be a good place to start playing with the API before you pull it into your RoR app. That example shows you how to get your key, too.

It looks like you can use the predefined APIs, or you can define a custom REST API associated with your Appery app? Instructions for building an API appear to be [here](http://devcenter.appery.io/documentation/rest-service/#Create_a_new_service).

Once you get the calls working from cURL (or other web request client of your choice), adding the calls to the RoR app should be more straightforward. Any of those gems could probably ease that process: I've only used RestClient personally, but found it very straightforward. 
Any of those call methods (cURL, other clients, the gems, etc) will allow you specify your URI, method (e.g. GET or POST), headers, request body (where appropriate), and will allow you to examine your response. Take a look at the gem documentation to see how those map exactly - it will vary slightly from tool to tool.

If you don't have prior experience with calling external APIs, and would like a conceptual explanation, I like [this article](http://rest.elkstein.org/2008/02/what-is-rest.html) as a (very short!) beginner's guide.

Comment: Thanks! Let me play around with the cURL commands then and I will get to reading that article.